# How can I parse the output of cmdlet to another?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I need to create a list of no longer active users in the OnPremise Active Directory?

Using the below  format as input:

```
User Name; user.Name@domain.com
John Doe; John.Doe@domain.net
Veki Jado; Veki.Jado@office.com
....
```

My goal here is to generate the list of which users can be safely removed by Paris g the above into:

```
Get-ADUser | Export-CSV
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you getting the input CSV from an Exchange cmldet? You can iterate through your input CSV rows with a foreach and then use `-LDAPFilter "(&(mail=$($row.mail))(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" `

Comment: What are the actual fields you can get for your input? If you can get the `samaccountname` for your users, then it can be as simple as `(Import-CSV users.csv).SamAccountName | Get-ADUser`. Do your on-prem usernames/UPNs/mail etc match your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to generate a list of inactive (disabled) Active Directory Users and output them into a CSV file?

Your statement of

> Using the below format as input:

is unclear to me though.
Is that the format you want your output CSV file to look like, or is it an input containing users informations for which you want to verify if they are still enabled in Active Directory?

Assuming it is the definition what your output should look like, you would achieve that with the following line of PowerShell code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\myoutputfile.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit 1:**

Based on your elaborations, I was able to reproduce the output that is actually really an array of strings formatted like this:

`FirstName LastName;firstname.lastname@domain.com`

So the following code should give you what you are looking for:

```
$theInputCollectionOfUsers = Get-AntiPhishPolicy -Identity 'Default anti-phishing policy' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TargetedUsersToProtect

[array]$adUsers = $null
foreach($user in $theInputCollectionOfUsers){
$userPrincipalName = $user.Split(";")[1]
[array]$adUsers += Get-ADUser -Identity $userPrincipalName
}
$adUsers | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Enabled | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\myoutputfile.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The `Enabled` property will return false positives under circumstances and should be avoided. When checking for actually disabled users you should use the `-LDAPFilter` property and check for [userAccountControl](http://www.selfadsi.de/ads-attributes/user-userAccountControl.htm)

Comment: Hi @powershell Ninja, not really, What I'd like to generate is the list of inactive AD users based on the input file like the above I showed.
I got the list from different Powershell cmd let like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-antiphishpolicy?view=exchange-ps hence I wanted to compare it against the AD to generate the inactive AD users.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer is that the right command? `Get-AntiPhishPolicy` doesn't return users

Comment: @Cpt.Whale this is the complete cmdlet that produces the output like the above. Get-AntiPhishPolicy -Identity 'Default anti-phishing policy' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TargetedUsersToProtect

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I updated my answer above, this should solve your question